# What statistical test should I use if the relationship between two variables is neither linear nor monotonic?

Tags: correlation, continuous-data, pearson-r, scatterplot, spearman-rho

I am confused. My scatterplot says that the relationship between the two variables is not linear, so I can't use Pearson's correlation and neither is it monotonic, so I can't use Spearman's correlation. From what I've learned these are assumptions that you have to meet so you can run those statistical tests. And considering that I don't meet any, I don't know what to do. Also, my variables are continuous.

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you say more about your situation, your data, & your goals? Can you paste your scatterplot into your question?

Comment: What are you trying to find out/show?

Comment: I'm trying to see if there's a significant correlation between health-related quality of life and perceived social support in inflammatory bowel disease. From my data it looks like everyone has very high perceived social support and I think it's for that reason that the distribution of the data on this variable is not normal and it's also very asimetrical and terribly skewed.

Comment: I've tried to transform the data to make it look more normal, but it doesn't work. It's still not normal, asimetrical and skewed. And of course, the relationship between those two variables doesn't look linear, at least for me. Considering the fact that the scores on the perceived social support are so high, is my hypothesis still valid?
Thanks!

Comment: I've added the scatterplot and the histogram. I feel so stupid right now.

Comment: Neither Pearson nor Spearman correlation is absurd or inapplicable here. What's important is their value, in each case small positive (presumably), which tells you that you have a weak relationship here. Whether there is underneath that something of clinical importance which is obscured by the effects of other variables is not something we can tell. I wouldn't call the skewness "terrible"; it's just negative skewness that makes sense.

Comment: It looks monotonic, just with a rather weak relationship.

Comment: If linearity were a prerequisite for running Pearson's correlation, then only perfect correlations would be calculated, and we would learn nothing from them. On the contrary, the main role of Pearson correlation is to _measure_ how well the data could be summarized by a linear relationship. Similar remarks apply to Spearman and monotonicity.

Comment: So it's ok if I use Pearson's correlation? If yes, then you are right: the relationship between the variables is very weak. 

Thank you so much for your answers!

Comment: You already used it, tacitly. Your $R^2$ is 0.141, so it's about 0.375 or 0.376.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you. I don't know why I complicated things so much and why something seemed so off to me.